# How to connect MSSQL using symfony odm

Tags: sql-server, azure, symfony, azure-sql-database

I am using symfony and try to connect with windows MSSQL Server using odm pdo_sqlsrv driver but getting the following error

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

even though i am able to connect using sql cmd.

Both Machines are on MS Azure.

Any Suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your connection string and add Timeout=[seconds] to your connection string.

Comment: Thank you for comment . tried but not succeed .. even though I can connect using sql cmd coomand line to the DB.